# Sliding Views Like whatsapp(android) in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uipagecontrol

I have to make sliding Views with Sliding tabs.The tabs are sliding and i have used collectionview for that and now the requirement is to slide the views correponding to the tab like in whatsapp app in android. Is there any optimum solution to acheive that other than scrollview,i have do it fast as i have to deliver it by tomorrow.[image]

Comment: You can use UIPageViewController and make the control easily using that

Comment: actually i have to change the whole architeture for that,as i am using this in almost every scene.

Comment: okay, in that case just wrap all your views in a scrollView. it is although memory intensive for number of pages >3 and also you might face touch interaction issue.

Comment: you should try this https://github.com/HeshamMegid/HMSegmentedControl

Comment: Yes,i am already facing that,thats why asking for optimum solution..

Comment: optimal solution is to use PageViewController, something like https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager

Comment: @Shubhank i have to work with views rather than view controllers,so is there any solution for that.

Comment: drop into [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow) @Diksha

Answer (score 1):

`SMSwipeableTabView` provides this functionality. 
SMSwipeableTabView is a custom control which is mixture of UIPageViewController and Scrollable Tab Bar. This is similar to Swipe view with tabs alyout in android. Any number of tabs can be added along with the swipeable views. User can fully customize the control.

To run the example project, clone the repo, and run pod install from the Example directory first. This provides pod so that you can implement easily.

**This library works with iOS version 8.0 and above. It is written in Swift.**

**iOS 8.0+ / Mac OS X 10.9+
Xcode 7**

Check below sample code :

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/smswipeabletabview

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,have achieved through gesture recognizers.